# xsltproc: xsl:version: only 1.1 features are supported

Tags: xslt, xsd, xml-parsing, xslt-1.0, libxml2

Not looking to do anything spectacular here, just looking for, really, any sort of simple `xslt` which will run from `xsltproc` and give reasonably interesting output -- but simple.

```
thufir@dur:~/jaxb/ship$ 
thufir@dur:~/jaxb/ship$ ls
a.xslt  shiporder.xml
thufir@dur:~/jaxb/ship$ 
thufir@dur:~/jaxb/ship$ cat shiporder.xml 
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<shiporder orderid="889923"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="shiporder.xsd">
  <orderperson>John Smith</orderperson>
  <shipto>
    <name>Ola Nordmann</name>
    <address>Langgt 23</address>
    <city>4000 Stavanger</city>
    <country>Norway</country>
  </shipto>
  <item>
    <title>Empire Burlesque</title>
    <note>Special Edition</note>
    <quantity>1</quantity>
    <price>10.90</price>
  </item>
  <item>
    <title>Hide your heart</title>
    <quantity>1</quantity>
    <price>9.90</price>
  </item>
</shiporder> 


thufir@dur:~/jaxb/ship$ 
thufir@dur:~/jaxb/ship$ trang shiporder.xml shiporder.xsd
thufir@dur:~/jaxb/ship$ 
thufir@dur:~/jaxb/ship$ ls
a.xslt  shiporder.xml  shiporder.xsd  xsi.xsd
thufir@dur:~/jaxb/ship$ 
thufir@dur:~/jaxb/ship$ cat shiporder.xsd 
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <xs:import namespace="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" schemaLocation="xsi.xsd"/>
  <xs:element name="shiporder">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element ref="orderperson"/>
        <xs:element ref="shipto"/>
        <xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" ref="item"/>
      </xs:sequence>
      <xs:attribute name="orderid" use="required" type="xs:integer"/>
      <xs:attribute ref="xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation" use="required"/>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
  <xs:element name="orderperson" type="xs:string"/>
  <xs:element name="shipto">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element ref="name"/>
        <xs:element ref="address"/>
        <xs:element ref="city"/>
        <xs:element ref="country"/>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
  <xs:element name="name" type="xs:string"/>
  <xs:element name="address" type="xs:string"/>
  <xs:element name="city" type="xs:string"/>
  <xs:element name="country" type="xs:NCName"/>
  <xs:element name="item">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element ref="title"/>
        <xs:element minOccurs="0" ref="note"/>
        <xs:element ref="quantity"/>
        <xs:element ref="price"/>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
  <xs:element name="title" type="xs:string"/>
  <xs:element name="note" type="xs:string"/>
  <xs:element name="quantity" type="xs:integer"/>
  <xs:element name="price" type="xs:decimal"/>
</xs:schema>
thufir@dur:~/jaxb/ship$ 
thufir@dur:~/jaxb/ship$ cat xsi.xsd 
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <xs:import schemaLocation="shiporder.xsd"/>
  <xs:attribute name="noNamespaceSchemaLocation" type="xs:NCName"/>
</xs:schema>
thufir@dur:~/jaxb/ship$ 
thufir@dur:~/jaxb/ship$ cat a.xslt 
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output method="text"/>
 <xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:copy-of select="unparsed-text(static-base-uri())"/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
thufir@dur:~/jaxb/ship$ 
thufir@dur:~/jaxb/ship$ xsltproc a.xslt shiporder.xml > output.xml
compilation error: file a.xslt line 1 element stylesheet
xsl:version: only 1.1 features are supported
xmlXPathCompOpEval: function static-base-uri not found
XPath error : Unregistered function
xmlXPathCompiledEval: evaluation failed
no result for shiporder.xml
thufir@dur:~/jaxb/ship$
```

The `xml` is [from](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/schema_example.asp) w3school -- frankly, just looking to generate some sort of output using `xsltproc`, which means `xslt` version 1, I believe.

Comment: It's telling you that it can't handle a stylesheet with version="2.0".

Comment: It **can** handle a stylesheet with version="2.0". It cannot handle 2.0 features.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`xsltproc` uses the `libxslt`processor which supports only XSLT 1.0 or 1.1 (in some configurations).

Your XSLT contains:

```
<xsl:copy-of select="unparsed-text(static-base-uri())"/>
```

`static-base-uri()` is an XPath 2.0 function, and your processor cannot handle it - which is why you see:

```
xmlXPathCompOpEval: function static-base-uri not found
XPath error : Unregistered function
```

Note that `unparsed-text()` is an XSLT 2.0 function and you would get an error with it too, if the processor ever got that far.

> just looking to generate some sort of output using `xsltproc`

Try the [identity transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_transform#Using_XSLT) for starters?

Comment: I kinda went on a tangent with https://xml.apache.org/xalan-j/overview.html which was easy to understand.  Xalan should be able to perform those identity transforms from this data easily enough (probably)?

Comment: The identity transform requires only XSLT 1.0 and both libxslt and Xalan (which are both XSLT 1.0 processors) will have no problems with it.